Your request could not be processed while apple developer enrollment
I have recently tried to enroll in the apple developer program but unable to do so. Whenever I accept the policy agreement then there is the popup showing the following error:

Your request could not be processed

I have also contacted apple customer support but no help from their side. The error doesn't mean anything. Then what should I do now ?
I have tried some following ways but none of them helped:

Switch internet from different network provider
Uninstall and Install App developer application multiple times
Shutdown and restart device several times
Setup iCloud successfully
Enable auto updates for macOS

Now, Is there any solution to enroll successfully or tp reset all the process so I can again start from scratch ?
